# Polar Coordinates Double Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Evaluate $\int(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}dA$ where $D$ is region enclosed by the two circles: $x^2+y^2=64$ and $x^2+(y-4)^2=16$.

I'm confused on what the limits of integration for the corresponding double integral will be once converted to polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You're integrating the region between two circles, one with centre at the origin and radius 8, one with centre at $(0,4)$ and radius 4. To solve the problem, find the angles of the points where the circles intersect to get the limits of integration for $\theta$ and use the equations of the circles as your upper and lower limits of integration for the radius.

Comment: So for theta would it be 0 --> 2pi?

Comment: No, the area you are integrating is somewhat like the intersection of a venn diagram visually. Find the points at which the two circles intersect, and then figure out the angles of these points using trigonometry.

Comment: Hint: when the points intersect, $x^2 + y^2 = 64 = 8y$

Comment: Isn't the only point where the two circles intersect at (0,8)?

Comment: My mistake, it is not a venn diagram. I presume then that the question is lacking for the area in the first circle, but not the second. In that case, there are a few ways to approach this, the easiest being to integrate over the area of the first circle, and then subtract the integral over the area of the second circle.

Comment: Alternatively, use polar coordinates, split it into an integral in the positive $y$ half plane and negative $y$ half plane. The negative half plane, i.e. $\theta$ in the interval $(\pi,2\pi)$ is easy. For the upper half plane, note that $y = r \sin \theta$ and then integrate from $r = 8 \sin \theta$ to $r = 8$.

Comment: Sorry about that.